# Ошибка при установке Usbrip

Tags: python, linux, debian

Пытался установить https://github.com/snovvcrash/usbrip

но при попытке установить, возникает ошибка:

```
>>>> Installing usbrip
Processing /home/oleg/usbrip-master
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-ylcsssf6-build/setup.py", line 81
        raise ValueError(f'{path} is not a path inside {here}')
                                                             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-ylcsssf6-build/
>>>> Failed to install usbrip using PyPI dependencies
```

Действовал согласно инструкции вводил:

```
~/usbrip$ chmod +x installers/install.sh
~/usbrip$ sudo -H installers/install.sh [-l/--local] [-s/--storages]
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Python 3 установлен?

Comment: Тут всё ок? https://github.com/snovvcrash/usbrip#deb-packages